# Filter based on values after join operation - MongoDB

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in the following format -

collection 1

```
{
    "_id": "col1id1",
    "name": "col1doc1",
    "properties": [ "<_id1>", "<_id2>", "<_id3>"]
}
```

collection 2

```
{
    "_id": "<_id1>",
    "name": "doc1",
    "boolean_field": false
}
{
    "_id": "<_id2>",
    "name": "doc2",
    "boolean_field": true
}
{
    "_id": "<_id3>",
    "name": "doc3",
    "boolean_field" : false
}
```

the desired output is -

```
{
    "_id": "col1id1",
    "name": "col1doc1",
    "property_names": ["doc1", "doc3"]
}
```

The field `proerties` of document in collection1 has three IDs of documents in collection2 but the output after join operation should contain only those which have the `boolean_field` value as `false`. How can I perform this filter with join operation in MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$lookup` can be used along with `$unwind` to achieve this.

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$properties"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "col2",
      localField: "properties",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "property_names"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "property_names": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "bool_field": false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$property_names"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "properties": {
        "$push": "$properties"
      },
      "property_names": {
        "$push": "$property_names"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "property_names": {
        "name": 1
      }
    }
  }
]);
```